# APL2, Compress each

Tags: apl

I want to compress `⌿` several vectors/matrices at the same time.

Here's my data:

```
txt←(3 3⍴'a')(3 3⍴'b')(3 3⍴'c')(3 3⍴'d')
  b←(0 1 0)(1 1 1)(1 1 0)(0 0 0)
```

Now, I want to compress each matrix in `txt` by corresponding Boolean vector in `b`:

```
b⌿¨txt
```

Here's what I expect to get back:

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│aaa│bbb│ccc│   │
│   │bbb│ccc│   │
│   │bbb│   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

I've tried this over at [tryapl.org](https://tryapl.org) and it behaves as I expect, but in APL2 I get a **DOMAIN ERROR** pointing at `b` and the Each glyph.

Are there any APL2 hackers here that could help me with this?
Is there another way of doing this without an explicit loop? Inner/Outer product?

Comment: [TryAPL permalink](https://tryapl.org/?a=%280%201%200%29%281%201%201%29%281%201%200%29%280%200%200%29%u233F%A8%283%203%u2374%27a%27%29%283%203%u2374%27b%27%29%283%203%u2374%27c%27%29%283%203%u2374%27d%27%29&run).

Comment: I've updated the title. Thank you for noting the name of the glyph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this fails in APL2 is that `⌿` is purely an operator in APL2, whereas in Dyalog APL it is a hybrid function/operator in that it acts like a function if it has an array on its left, but as an operator if it has a function on its left.

In Dyalog APL, since `⌿` acts as a normal function, the items of `b` and `txt` will be paired up by `¨` as you expect.

In APL2, `b` will be bound to to the monadic operator `⌿` as its sole operand and then the entire derived function `b⌿` will be applied with `¨` to each item of `txt`. Needless to say, the entire `b` (a vector of vectors) is not an appropriate left argument for a single application of `⌿`.

You can get around this problem by wrapping `⌿` in a function, and then using `¨` on that wrapper function. The wrapper is as simple as:

```
r←x R y
r←x⌿y
```

Comment: Great explanation and even better work-around. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In GNU APL (an APL2 derivative) you can put parentheses around ⌿ or around ⌿¨ :

```
      txt←(3 3⍴'a')(3 3⍴'b')(3 3⍴'c')(3 3⍴'d')
        b←(0 1 0)(1 1 1)(1 1 0)(0 0 0)

      b(⌿)¨txt
 aaa  bbb  ccc   
      bbb  ccc   
      bbb     

      b(⌿¨)txt
 aaa  bbb  ccc   
      bbb  ccc   
      bbb
```

In original IBM APL2 (PC version) none of these seem to work. The reasons might be that ⌿ is ambiguous (it could mean "function compress" as well as "operator reduce") and the ISO standard (which is implemented by both IBM APL2 and by GNU APL) did not say how to resolve this ambiguity. The parentheses force ¨ to take ⌿ as a function.